# Java regex : find the last occurrence of a string using Matcher.matches()

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have following input String:

`abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno`

Number of dot characters may vary in the input. I want to extract the word after the last `.` (i.e. `mno` in the above example). I am using the following `regex` and its working perfectly fine:

```
String input = "abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^.]+$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

However, I am using a third party library which does this matching ([Kafka Connect](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/RegexRouter.java) to be precise) and I can just provide the regex pattern to it. The issue is, this library (whose code I can't change) uses `matches()` instead of `find()` to do the matching, and when I execute the same code with `matches()`, it doesn't work e.g.:

```
String input = "abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^.]+$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The above code doesn't print anything. As per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), `matches()` tries to match the whole String. Is there any way I can apply similar logic using `matches()` to extract `mno` from my input String?

Comment: Use `.*\.(.+)` and get Group 1 value.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing two separate problems. Are you extracting or matching? Or both? Because `matches()` alone won't extract anything.

Comment: You want mno? :-)

Comment: `".*\\.([^.]*)"` should do

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works well. Could you add this as an answer? I will then accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
".*\\.([^.]*)"
```

It matches

- `.*\.` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last `.` char
- `([^.]*)`  - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than a dot.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZWAtzN/1) and the Regulex graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To extract a word after the last `.` per your instruction you could do this without Pattern and Matcher as following:

```
String input = "abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno";
String getMe = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(".")+1, input.length());
System.out.println(getMe);
```

Comment: I agree with this. .matches returns a boolean, so it will only tell you if there is a match or not. You could still use matches to confirm if there are any '.' characters at all, and then use the code above to extract.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Use `.*` at the beginning to enable it to match the entire input.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String input = "abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*([^.]{3})$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

---

```
abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno
mno
```

---

This is a better pattern if the dot really is anywhere: `".*\\.([^.]+)$"`